# Access permissions of /dev/mem

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I have a set of questions regarding `/dev/mem`:

1. Many articles on the net, seem to refer `/dev/mem` as the gateway to `"Physical RAM"`. But if I am right, `/dev/mem` is the gateway to the `"Physical Address Space"` of the processor which might include control registers of many HW peripherals and not just the RAM? Please, correct me if I am wrong!
2. In order to prevent attackers from misusing `/dev/mem` and altering kernel memory, a flag `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` needs to be enabled which will prevent user apps from accessing physical address space beyond 1MB. I checked the config file on my PC (Ubuntu) and found that `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM = y`. And I wrote a program which tries to read to physical memory beyond 1 MB and I was able to read! No segmentation fault or any `Operation NOT Permitted` error. How is this possible?

My program roughly looks like this:

```
fd = open ( "/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
ptr = (int*) mmap(0, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ, fd, myAddress & (~MAP_MASK));
printf("%d", *ptr);
```

Comment: You are actually reading or just mmap-ing it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Yes, you're right, /dev/mem allows you to map any physical address, including non-RAM memory mapped IO.  This can can be useful for a quick and dirty hack to access some hardware device without writing a kernel driver.
2. CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM makes the kernel check addresses in /dev/mem with  `devmem_is_allowed()` in `arch/x86/mm/init.c`, and the comment there explains:

   ```
   * On x86, access has to be given to the first megabyte of ram because that area
   * contains bios code and data regions used by X and dosemu and similar apps.
   * Access has to be given to non-kernel-ram areas as well, these contain the PCI
   * mmio resources as well as potential bios/acpi data regions.
   ```

   your address `0xFFFF0000` is quite likely to be non-RAM, since BIOSes typically put IO memory just below 4GB, so that's why you're able to map it even with STRICT_DEVMEM.

Answer (score 3):

What does the follow yield:

```
cat /dev/mem | wc
```

I get:

```
cat: /dev/mem: Operation not permitted
   1908   11791 1048576
```

So for me it does stop at 1MB.

Note that cat uses open, not mmap so its not an identical test.

Are you sure you're reading beyond 1MB?

Comment: This is the program I am running
[link](http://designsomething.org/leopardboard/f/22/t/77.aspx)
And then I run 'code'sudo ./a.out 0xFFFF0000'code' and I get the output as 
'code'/dev/mem opened.
Memory mapped at address 0x7fbf1409f000.
Value at address 0x0 (0x7fbf1409f000): 0xF000E819'code'

Comment: I need to write a /dev/mem driver that will access all of physical memory, this is for a memory diagnostic tool. If I change CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM to =N, will that allow access to all phy. memory? Do I have to rebuild the kernel or just the mem driver module? thx