# open /dev/mem - Operation not permitted

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I am working on ubuntu.

I am trying to open `/dev/mem` and i am getting `permission denied`

```
int32_t open_memdev()
{
        int32_t fd;

        fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
                printf("Failed to open /dev/mem : %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return-EINVAL;
        }

        return fd;
}
```

This code always prints `"Failed to open /dev/mem : Operation not permitted"`

I have searched for this on SO

1. [access-permissions-of-dev-mem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134984/access-permissions-of-dev-mem)
2. [accessing-mmaped-dev-mem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891979/accessing-mmaped-dev-mem)

These q's seem to discuss the issue of not being able to access above 1 MB, but my problem is that i am unable to open even once.

**Addtitional details if they help:**

1) I checked my configuration that CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM is enabled.

```
2) ls -l /dev/mem
crw-r----- 1 root kmem 1, 1 2014-03-13 13:57 /dev/mem
```

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: What is your ["`id`"](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_id.htm), are you root?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access permissions of /dev/mem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134984/access-permissions-of-dev-mem)

Comment: @osgx I clarified the point of this Q being a duplicate of the one you mentioned. Request you to look at that part in my question. No i am not root. With root i am able to read.I want to read without being a root as a normal user

Comment: @Manty you cannot. That's what permissions are for.

Comment: Please explain why do you need to access `/dev/mem` from an ordinary id ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot read `/dev/mem` if you are not *root*.

<sup>There is no reason for an ordinary application to access `/dev/mem`, i.e. the *physical* RAM, since applications are running in *virtual memory* !</sup>

If you change the permission of `/dev/mem` to enable that (you should not), you will open a huge security hole in your system. Only trusted root processes should access `/dev/mem`. See [mem(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html)

(you could use [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques if so wanted, or run your program with `sudo`)

If you need to access [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) in the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) of some other [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), consider [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) e.g. `/proc/1234/mem` for process of pid 1234.

Comment: ok, let's say I want to open the huge security hole. How can I setup dev/mem so every user can use it? (I need it for a test)

Comment: @Zibri: run your program as root with `sudo` or make your program setuid

Comment: I know that I was searching for a way to have /dev/mem free to use for all (for a test study). Anyway I found it. I just had to comment one line in mem.c and add return 0; instead.

Comment: For some reason even as root I still cannot open it.

Comment: Access to /dev/mem is often subject to additional restrictions even when the user is root, such as from SELinux's memory_device_t or from kernel lockdown (often automatically initiated from Secure Boot), see https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9b9d8dda1ed72e9bd560ab0ca93d322a9440510e